# OnCreate method is always called

Tags: android, android-activity

I read the Android documentation and I don't understand one step:

When I press a button my app shows the Activity2 with the startActivity(intent) method, then I use the back button and my app shows the Activity1 again. If I want show the Activity2 I press the button again, and my app always call onCreate to the Activity2.

The Android documentation says the method onCreate is called only when is starting or when is destroyed.

Why is this happening?

Thanks!!

Regars.

Comment: What makes you think that your activity hasn't been destroyed? Put some breakpoints or some logs in each callback method (onCreate, onDestroy for example) and you will see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The OnCreate() method is called each time the activity is displayed (created). So each time you call the startActivity(intent) method, the OnCreate  method will be called.

Check the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you pressed the back button when you were in `Activity2`, which by default destroys the activity you're currently on. You can override `onDestroy()` and print a debug message to confirm (make sure to call `super`).

Instead of retaining the same `Activity2` object, you should leverage `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` and `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)` to save and restore your `Activity2`'s state, respectively.

Technically you could use the `Bundle` object passed into `onCreate(Bundle)` as they are the same object. The docs recommend `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle)`:

> Most implementations will simply use `onCreate(Bundle)` to restore their state, but it is sometimes convenient to do it here after all of the initialization has been done or **to allow subclasses to decide whether to use your default implementation.**

Answer (score 0):

It's completely normal beheviour. You are calling startActivity() so activity is starting. That's all. This method is called also when you are changing configuration - i.e rotating the device. Moreover - it's also possible that Activity1.onCreate() will be called after pressing back button, while it's going background and can be disposed by system if more ram is needed.